# Styles not Loading up Properly in Gmail

Tags: css, email, gmail, html-email

I'm having a strange issue with my email not rendering any styles in Gmail. I'm using CleverReach for the Email.

I didn't have faced this issue before.

I have also tried to make all the styles inline but still with no luck. All of the other mailboxes are rendering the email ok. Similarly, we don't have to do the in-lining stuff as these Email Marketting Services do the inline stuff automatically when email is sent.

[Here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/14Fd2fwMPu5qITtb5WIeHavbLNJUJuSAEZHJjX0uy4Z0/edit?usp=sharing) is the code to look into.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I CSS inlined your code via MailChimp's tool:
http://beaker.mailchimp.com/inline-css

And then sent it to gmail and it appears to render correctly.

Here's the modified HTML:

http://jsfiddle.net/9KRaB/

Gmail strips `<style>` tags so unless its inlined, styles are stripped in Gmail. Perhaps you can "view source" on how CleverReach is inlining your CSS by viewing the HTML once its received in Gmail. There might be something in how your mailer is inlining it that causes the problem.

Comment: Ironically it is working with mailchimp fine even without using inline tools, there might be some problems with CleverReach, as it is working absolutely fine when used with mailchimp or campaign monitor.

Comment: Thats because MailChimp and Campaign Monitor automatically runs their CSS-inline tools on your HTML prior to sending. So that's probably the case, CleverReach isn't able to inline your CSS properly :)

Comment: As earlier said, I have tested it in both ways on CleverReach using inliner tool & without inliner, but the issue does look to be with CleverReach.

Comment: It looks like CleverReach is not able to inlining CSS - is this still the case in 2016? I think this is the case and renders CleverReach unusable for me.